# how to change php encoding in database?

Tags: php

I have got mysql database in utf8_general_ci and php page with utf-8 charset.
Why in php page i have got some text with bad encoding (which takes from data)?
http://likebox.ru/fbtn/

Comment: You need to change it in database, not in PHP, no?

Comment: in database i have got utf-8 http://gyazo.com/8f0e94d861889e32aef117d4de3a2dfc.png?1326638287

Comment: When I `curl` that page, I'm receiving actual question mark characters, not garbage. This seems to be a problem in the server-side code.

Comment: I think the utf8 from database with utf8 from php have not any inconsistence, erros, etc.. Do you utf8 encode the data when save to db..?

Comment: If you look at the data in the database directly (in phpMySQLadmin), does it show up correctly?

Comment: How i can convert to utf-8 when i write to database? (may be this is problem?)

Comment: `utf8_encode($data)` do the job, but I don't know without investigate if this solve your trouble.

Comment: with directly add from phpmyadmin i have got same error

Comment: http://likebox.ru/fbtn/ - with utf8_encode() same problem with text from database;

Comment: this problem nly with russian text, may be it can help?

Comment: Answer is:

`mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` 
need this string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name_here DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE new_char_set_here;
```

Comment: file in utf-8 too http://gyazo.com/2cfb3e55256d78117efa26cbf496ed82.png?1326638955